# Manera correcta de preguntar esta pregunta con "usted"

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras

En la letra de una canción, el artista canta:

> ¿Quién crees que eres usted?

Eso a mí me suena incorrecto, pero la verdad no estoy seguro como se preguntaría esa pregunta. Quizás, *¿quién se cree usted?*. Pero eso ya parece cambiar un poco el matiz. Lo que me confunde a mí es porque *crees* no está en forma de usted: *cree*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edwar, por lo menos en Colombia, también se consideraría incorrecto porque los verbos no corresponden a la persona de la que se habla (usted) sino a «tú».

Según mi experiencia, las siguientes expresiones son válidas:

- ¿Y quién se cree usted que es?
- ¿Y usted quién se cree que es [pues]?

Por ejemplo:

> ¿Y usted quién se cree que es para venir a decirme qué debo hacer?

Comment: El OP sabe que no es valido. La pregunta es por que la cancion se escribe asi.

Comment: @mdewey mi interpretación es que Edwar no sabe que es incorrecta la expresión sino que sospecha («me suena incorrecto, pero la verdad no estoy seguro»).  El título de la pregunta dice «Manera correcta de preguntar esta pregunta con "usted"». Esa es la inquietud que estoy respondiendo. Para poder responder «por que la cancion se escribe asi» habría que conocer el título y autor de la canción, identificar la variante del español que usa y, tal vez, preguntarle al autor.